# Can't set a proper jquery system path, keep geting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'jquery' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I'm a beginner in programing taking a js online course on object oriented programming with some exercises and I got stuck in this error, maybe it's because the course is a couple of years old. All im trying to do is load a button to the page with no functionality, just for testing.
This is the error:

(index):19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'jquery' of undefined
at (index):19

index 19 is this line of code: `System.paths['jquery'] = './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';`

Thanks for your patience and help.

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Drones</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

  <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules\material-design-lite\dist\material.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    System.paths['jquery'] = './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
    System.import('src/app.js');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The button:

```
import {BaseElement} from './base-element.js';

export class Button extends BaseElement {

    constructor(title) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
    }

    getElementString() {
        return `
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
          ${this.title}
        </button>
        `;
    }
}
```

Base element:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export class BaseElement {

    constructor() {
        this.element = null; // jQuery object
    }

    appendToElement(el) {
        this.createElement();
        el.append(this.element);
    }

    createElement() {
        let s = this.getElementString();
        this.element = $(s);
    }

    getElementString() {
        throw 'Please override getElementString() in BaseElement';
    }

}
```

the app:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {Car} from './classes/car.js';
import {Drone} from './classes/drone.js';
import {fleet} from './fleet-data.js';
import {FleetDataService} from './services/fleet-data-service.js';
import { Button } from './ui/button.js';

let b = new Button ('Click me');
b.appendToElement($('body'));
```

Comment: I don't think `System.<>` has been used since webpack 1 but someone might be able to correct me on that. Regardless, it appears you're using some very old javascript. If you post where you're pulling this online course from we might be able to help more but as it is I think you need to find a new course.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A friend of mine helped by adding more recent stuff to the code.

Comment: I have run up against this exact problem. The course is [Pluralsight Object Oriented Programming in Javascript - ES6](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/javascript-es6-object-oriented-programming/table-of-contents). It is dated 2016. I am still wrestling with this.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was downgrading the dependencies. What worked was:

npm install -save jquery@2.2.3

and

npm install -save systemjs@0.19.27